# str_replace “|” using php

Tags: php

I want to insert `"|"` in place of space `" "` using `str_replace`, but when I use it

```
str_replace("|", " ", $word);
```

All space between the words were deleted. Any help?

-- The code

```
$word=explode(" ",$FromForm);
$word_count - str_word_count($_post['xxx'];
for($i=0;$i<=$word_count;$i++) {
   echo str_replace("|"," ",$word[$i]);
   //it echos fine without the string replace
}
```

Comment: The code you've written not inserts, but replaces all occurrences of `|` to a space.

Comment: Can you give some example please?

Comment: Yeah, you're finding pipes and replacing them with spaces. Also, use single quotes so special characters aren't an issue.

Comment: I would really like to see, what is in `$word`

Comment: @Marcel the performance of string parsing for non-interpolated strings is equal for single or double quoted strings.

Comment: @zerms mistake in english, yes replaces, but it removes all space

Comment: @Jean, could you please show your whole code, with the value of $word as well

Comment: @starx updated the question, pls check

Comment: Jean, do a var_dump($word) and put the output on your question too.

Comment: @Jean, since you exploded $FromForm by `" "`, there will be nothing to replace by str_replace later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the function the wrong way, if you are trying to replace certain text with `|`, then you have to do something like this.

```
str_replace(" ","|",$word);
```

**UPDATE**

Since you exploded $FromForm by `" "`, there will be nothing to replace by str_replace later on.

Comment: No I am trying to insert a | where there is a space

Comment: you are right, I got absorbed in what I was doing, but got a way through that too :D.  I am accepting your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can try `str_replace(" "," | ",$word);`

Comment: It removes the "space" as before

Comment: Your question states you want to "Insert | instead of spaces". What is it you really want to accomplish? (that is, give an example input and result)

Comment: @joel, the above solution does not work, it simply removes the spaces not insert the "|".  updated the question

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm still having a hard time understanding what and why you are trying to do, but…)*

Replace everything with:

```
$word = str_replace(" ", "|", $FromForm);
```